# What is highest count that sticks can have?

Tags: probability

There is a bag with sticks in it and lenghts are integers. We know that if you take any 3 stick and add them end to end, they can not make a triangle. Longest stick has the lenght of 120. What is highest count that sticks can have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1,a_2,...a_k,120$ be the sticks, and sorted so that $a_i\leq a_j$ for $i<j$.

We have $a_3\geq a_1+a_2, a_4\geq a_2+a_3$ and so on.

So for maximum number of sticks it must be fibonacci-lentgh sticks $1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55$ and $120$ so the highest count is $11$.

Answer (score 1):

Let the two smallest sticks have length $a$ and $b$. Then the next smallest is $\ge a+b$, the next is $\ge 2a+b$, the next $\ge 3a+2b$, the next $\ge 5a+3b$, and so on. After a while we get to next is $\ge 55a+34b$, and then its over. It is optimal to pick $a=b=1$. Make a minor adjustment at the end to make the biggest $120$ rather than $89$.